# Como puedo utilizar destructuring en un array de objetos

Tags: javascript

la funcion debe recibir como parametro un arreglo de objetos con las siguientes caracteristicas: Nombre, Apellido, Curso, Nota, Conducta (Boolean). La funcion debe retornar "El estudiante (Nombre y apellido) del curso (curso), tiene una nota de (Nota) y debe tener una longitud de minimo 10 objetos"

pero no se utilizar destructuring, es decir no se como aplicarlo a varios objetos

```
const a = (estudiantes) => {
   result = { name: nombre, lastname: apellido ,  note: nota, course: curso } = estudiantes
   return result;
   console.log(result)
}
a (estudiantes)

console.log(a(estudiantes))

let estudiantes = [
    {
      id: 1,
      nombre: "Boby",
      apellido: "rodrigues",
      nota: 17,
      curso: "Spartan Developers",
    }
];
    {
      id: 2,
      nombre: "Eliezer",
      apellido: "Gil",
      nota: 16,
      curso: "Spartan Developers",   
    },
      {
      id: 3 ,
      nombre: "Fabiana",
      apellido: "rodrigues",
      nota: 18,
      curso: "Spartan Developers",
        },
    {
      id: 4,
      nombre: "Rebeca",
      apellido: "Mendez",
      nota: 20,
      curso: "Spartan Developers",
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      nombre: "Reiner",
      apellido: "Ramires",
      nota: 12,
      curso: "Spartan Developers",
    },
    ]
```

Comment: Hola  no entendí mucho la pregunta pero si quieres desconstruir el objeto del array al recórrerlo podrías al utilizar map(({nombre, apellido, curso}) => {}) y luego de eso dentro del método hacer log con literals de esa oración que necesitas

Comment: Buenas noches, amigo no entiendo como aplicarlo en el codigo

Comment: Hola  estudiantes.map(({nombre, apellido}) => {console.log(‘nombre ‘ + nombre)})

Comment: Hola!! se aplicaria de esta forma 

const a = (estudiantes) => {
    estudiantes.map(({nombre, apellido, curso, nota}) => { console.log(`El estudiante ${nombre,aplellido} del curso ${curso}, tiene una nota de ${nota}`)})  
   
}
a(estudiantes)

Comment: si es asi me sale el siguente error !!-- ReferenceError: cannot access `estudiantes` before initialization y no comprendo porque

Comment: Hola  en el log ` El estudiante de ${nombre} y apellido ${apellido}! `

Comment: si es asi me sale el siguente error !!-- ReferenceError: cannot access estudiantes before initialization y no comprendo porque, yo veo el codigo con node

Comment: Hola , Coloca el objeto de tipo array arriba de la función

Comment: listo ya entendi porque no corria, era porque al momento que el termial lee el cogido, empezaba desde la funcion y no desde el el array cierto

Comment: Hola  Buenisimo ;)

Comment: amigo una pregunta, con ese mismo objeto tengo que sustraer solo el elemento nota   de todo el objeto, sumar todo el valor y dividirlo por la cantidad de alumnos, como escribiria el codigo utilizando el destructurin

Comment: Seria de esta forma

const promedioEscolar = (estudiante) => {
    estudiantes.map(({nota}) => { console.log(`El promedio escolar es ${nota.reduce((a,b)=>a+b/10)}`)}) 
}
promedioEscolar(estudiantes)

Comment: para obtener solo el valor del elemento nota dentro del objeto estudiante es asi
const promedioEscolar = (estudiante) => {
    estudiantes.map(({nota}) => { 
        let result = estudiantes.map.reduce((a, b) => a + b / 10);
     console.log(`El resultado de la funcion es: ${result}`);
     return result;
    })  
}
let resultpromedioEscolar = promedioEscolar(estudiantes)

Answer (score 1):

para lo que preguntabas en los comentarios:

```js
      let estudiantes = [
          {
            id: 1,
            nombre: "Boby",
            apellido: "rodrigues",
            nota: 17,
            curso: "Spartan Developers",
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            nombre: "Eliezer",
            apellido: "Gil",
            nota: 16,
            curso: "Spartan Developers",   
          },
            {
            id: 3 ,
            nombre: "Fabiana",
            apellido: "rodrigues",
            nota: 18,
            curso: "Spartan Developers",
              },
          {
            id: 4,
            nombre: "Rebeca",
            apellido: "Mendez",
            nota: 20,
            curso: "Spartan Developers",
          },
          {
            id: 5,
            nombre: "Reiner",
            apellido: "Ramires",
            nota: 12,
            curso: "Spartan Developers",
          },
          ];

          const a = (est) => {

             // Lo que preguntaste de recorrer
             est.map(({nombre, apellido}) => {
              console.log(`alumno ${nombre} de apellido ${apellido}`);
             });


             // Lo que preguntaste de sumar el total de notas por la cant de alumno

             let notas = est.map((al) => {return al.nota});
             let num_total_est = estudiantes.length;

             let sum_notas = notas.reduce((a, b) => a + b);

             return sum_notas / num_total_est;


          }

          console.log(a(estudiantes));
```

Comment: amigo y para dejar de molestar y ya si esto no se como hacerlo y es tener una validacion, si La conducta del estudiante es true y su nota es mayor a 10, entonces se imprima por consola un mensaje diciendo "El estudiante pasa de curso", en cambio, si la conducta del estudiante es false y sin importar su nota se imprima por consola "El estudiante reprueba el curso", y si la nota es menor a 10, tambien imprima "El estudiante reprueba el curso"

Comment: en eso no tengo idea de como hacerlo

Comment: se que si utilizo un for se puede pero no se como aplicarlo

Comment: una pregunta , que significa el "al"

Comment: El elemento que recorre por posicion, que se almacena en una variable como ejemplo al seria alumno

Comment: amigo y para dejar de molestar y ya si esto no se como hacerlo y es tener una validacion, si La conducta del estudiante es true y su nota es mayor a 10, entonces se imprima por consola un mensaje diciendo "El estudiante pasa de curso", en cambio, si la conducta del estudiante es false y sin importar su nota se imprima por consola "El estudiante reprueba el curso", y si la nota es menor a 10, tambien imprima "El estudiante reprueba el curso, se que se puede hacer con un :"for of" pero no se como hacerlo